# Similar SQL queries returning different results

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are the SQL Queries:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT count(thread) AS total 
          FROM comments
          WHERE thread=1
          AND parent_id=0
          ";

$sql2 = "SELECT count(thread) AS total 
          FROM comments, users 
          WHERE thread=1
          AND parent_id=0
          AND users.user_id=comments.user_id 
          ";

$sql3 = "SELECT comments.*, users.username AS username
        FROM comments, users 
        WHERE thread=1
        AND parent_id=0
        AND users.user_id=comments.user_id 
        ORDER BY date
        LIMIT 10, 5
        ";
```

My question is why would $sql1 and $sql2 would return two different results?

$sql1 returns 61 rows

$sql2 returns 56 rows

The 5th line in $sql2 is just for testing, is not required, is just a variation of $sql1 which gets the total rows for a pagination.

Comment: Have you manually checked the results to see the problem?, drop the count and do a select *.

Comment: Have you got your queries scrambled up?  Why have you presented sql3 if you ask nothing about it?  The LIMIT clause should probably be removed.

Comment: $sql3 is for a pagination so i only want a portion not all, if i remove the limit in in $sql3 in willl return the same as $sql2

Comment: Please please please stop using that bad implied join syntax. It is a very poor techinique which results in difficulty to maintain, lack of understanding of joins and accidental cross joins. The explicit join syntax has been around since 1992 (at least in the standard, I don't know when mysql picked it up) and there is no excuse for not using it in 2011.

Comment: What is the right join syntax?

Comment: Ok, i see, you mean using INNER JOIN and OUTTER JOIN

Comment: And `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN` and plain `JOIN`. Some prefer `INNER JOIN` over `JOIN`, as it makes the type of join explicit. MySQL supported `JOIN` clauses by version [3.23](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some comments don't belong to active user?

Do:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM comments
WHERE thread=1
AND parent_id=0
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users
                WHERE users.user_id=comments.user_id)
```

Does that return >0?

Comment: Thanks this are the 5 missing rows. 56 + 5 = 61

Comment: There were 5 entries with user_id = 0 and user 0 doesn't exist ofcourse

Comment: Then you need to fix your data integrity with foreign key constraints.

Comment: Im using constraints on my likes and flags tables. But i don't see how a foreign key constraints can fix my data integrity, can you elaborate please? also, do foreign key constraint work MyiSAM engine or only in innoBB? im using MyiSAM for now.

Comment: RE: foreign keys and MyISAM. See ["MySQL 5.1 Reference §1.8.5.4. Foreign Keys"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, some of the comments were created by users that no longer exist.  That is, of the 61 rows in the *comments* table matching the thread/parent criteria, 56 have a user ID that is recorded in the *users* table and 5 have a user ID that is not recorded in the *users* table.  This suggests you need to add a foreign key constraint on your *comments* table that references the *users* table (which will require a primary key constraint on your *users* table).

Comment: @Pable: if you add the foreign key make sure you use InnoDB as a storage engine. MyISAM will let you define the FK constraint but will silently ignore it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: which makes a mockery of the term 'constraint' since the so-called constraint doesn't actually constrain anything.

Comment: @a_horse: I'm not disputing that MySQL works that way.  I'm just saying that a constraint that doesn't constrain isn't really a constraint - and MySQL (with engines other than InnoDbB) allowing that makes a mockery of the term 'constraint'...  It's not your fault.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and what exactly is the gain on using a foreign key constraint between the 'users' and 'comments' table?

Comment: @Pablo: if the DBMS enforces the constraint implied by the foreign key, then you will not be able to insert a row into the comments table when the user ID is not listed in the users table (or update a row with a user ID that is not listed in the users table).  You will also not be able to delete a row from the users table while there are any rows in the comments table that contain the user ID.  Between them, the two aspects of the FK constraint ensure that when there are 61 rows in the comments table, all 61 rows will be returned by your `$sql2` query.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, i see how it can be help data integrity, but what if i need to delete a user or comment wouldn't there be a problem?

Comment: @Pablo: deleting a comment is not a problem; it just goes.  Deleting a user is a problem - do you, or do you not, want to know which user (even if now deleted) created the comment?  Or do you want to delete a user's comments when the user is deleted?  You probably want to keep the comment, but update the user ID to a surrogate user (the Community User in SO terms), or mark a user who made comments as deleted rather than physically deleting the record from the user table (so the comments remain correctly attributed, but no further comments can be added for the user, etc).

Comment: @Jonathan Thank you very much for your time, im definitely making this FK constraint on this table. It makes sense to keep user's comments after they delete their account because if their comments are deleted then child comments(replies) will become unreachable(burried with no existing parent comment) :)

Answer (score 0):

`$sql2` is called an "[inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join)". As DVK points out, inner joins don't return rows from a table when there's no row in the other table matching the join condition (`users.user_id=comments.user_id`). A [left join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) from `comments` with `users` in this case would match all rows from the `comments` table that are matched in $sql1, with columns taken from `users` set to NULL when there isn't a matching row from `users`.

```
-- equivalent to $sql2
SELECT count(c.thread) AS total 
  FROM comments AS c
    INNER JOIN users ON users.user_id=comments.user_id 
  WHERE c.thread=1
   AND c.parent_id=0

-- should return same total as $sql1
SELECT count(c.thread) AS total 
  FROM comments
    LEFT JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id=c.user_id 
  WHERE c.thread=1
   AND c.parent_id=0
```

Comment: `$sql1` does not do any join at all. It's a simple count on a single table (*comments*). Did you mean `$sql2`?

Comment: @a_horse: yes, indeed. Thanks for the catch.